# Using google sign-in button

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am using the google sign-in button everything looks to be working fine, But where i have issues is the callbacks from the response, How to get the sign-in details to feed into my DB.
i used the example code on https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button (STEP:5)

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
  if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
    // Update the app to reflect a signed in user
    // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
    document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
  } else {
    // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
    // Possible error values:
    //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
    //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
    //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
    console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
}
```

This is the error i am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: ext is not defined Sign-in state: user_signed_out`

Answer (score 0):

I keep getting the exact same problem. Its tempting to ditch the google sign in and just use your own.... or facebook. To fix this you can revoke access to your application and then sign in again. I did this by...

```
    if (AccessToken){
        var revokeUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' + AccessToken;

        // Perform an asynchronous GET request.
        $http.jsonp(revokeUrl).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data)
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                console.log(data)
            });
    }
```

Notice that it seems there are two callbacks, first one comes back and says it worked! Then the other comes back saying:
error: "user_signed_out".

I have not found a way around this other than the way i just explained.

### ANSWER

My problem was solved as soon as i realized the following...
I was not using a sub domain....

testsite.com

however when i changed it to www.testsite.com it worked perfectly and flawlessly.

Please make sure that you guys have the proper sub domain.